# Celery task not executing in Django project with Redis broker

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm working on a Django project where I'm using Celery with a Redis broker to run asynchronous tasks. I have a task that is supposed to run every minute, but it's not executing as expected. The task is received by the Celery worker, but it doesn't seem to be executed.

Here's the code for my task:

```
# socials/tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@shared_task
def hello():
    logger.info("Hello")
    print("Hello")
```

And here's my Celery configuration in Django settings:

```
# settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'  # I'm running Redis locally

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute': {
        'task': 'socials.tasks.hello',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')
    },
}
```

I'm running the Celery worker and beat services with the following commands:

```
celery -A my_project worker --loglevel=info
celery -A my_project beat --loglevel=info
```

The worker log shows that the worker is running and the socials.tasks.hello task is registered:

```
[tasks]
  . socials.tasks.hello
```

The beat log shows that the beat service is running and connected to the Redis broker:

```
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
```

However, the hello task is not executing. There are no error messages in the logs, and the task doesn't print "Hello" or log the message "Hello".

I've checked that the Redis server is running, and the worker and beat services seem to be able to connect to it. I've also tried running the task synchronously in a Django shell, and it executes correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas why the task might not be executing, or how I can further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest creating celery.py file to create a Celery app.

This celery.py file contains all the configuration parameters for Celery.

You can try it out.

```
# my_project/celery.py

import os
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')
# Create Celery instance
app = Celery('my_project_celery')

# Set broker and result_backend
app.conf.broker_url = "redis://localhost:6379/1"
app.conf.result_backend = "redis://localhost:6379/0"

# Set timezone and content type
app.conf.timezone = "UTC"
app.conf.accept_content = ['application/json']
app.conf.task_serializer = 'json'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'json'
app.conf.beat_scheduler = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'

# Set Task function files `my_project/tasks.py`
app.conf.imports = ["my_project.tasks"]

# Set Tasks
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "every-minute": {
        "task": "socials.tasks.hello",
        "schedule": 60.0 # you can change crontab()
    }
}

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

If you are in `development mode`, I suggest using the following command:

```
celery -A my_project.celery worker -l info -B
```

If you are in `production mode`, I suggest using the following command:

```
# terminal 1
celery -A my_project.celery worker --loglevel=info
# terminal 2
celery -A my_project.celery beat --loglevel=info
```